How to inject and extract a high frequency modulated signal onto and from the AC powerline?
I'm generating a square wave carrier signal of 125 kHz using 555 timer, I modulate it with a data signal generated from ATmega32 Tx pin (UART 9600 Baudrate) using OOK-Modulation, and now I'm trying to figure out how to send this modulated signal over a 220 V, AC 50 Hz powerline and being able to receive it on the receive side (Another ATmega32 Rx pin). Since I am new to this concept I need help on how exactly to inject the signal onto the AC powerline and extract it on the other end.

Try searching for 'powerline communications application notes'. AN5120 and AN10903 are on the first page of results. Read them, and then ask for clarification on what you don't understand.

Have you looked into baluns?

why do you want to do this? ... what problem are you trying to solve? ... please update your question ... do not write a comment

The short answer is that you need to impedance match the transmission line you're going to use. You're not taking that into account, so if you'll receive anything, it's probably going to be noise transported partially as differential noise between conductors and partially as free-space field. That's not powerline.
Sadly, that transmission line's impedance is cyclostationary (so, somewhat random, but tends to repeat regularly) with 100 Hz (twice grid frequency). So, your impedance matching either needs to have a low-enough output impedance to work even under the lowest-impedance situation, or you need your impedance matching to be adaptive. The former situation would assume you put in a lot of power, so that the device becomes hard to design. The second option means that you need your analog frontend to be a lot smarter than your 555-based solution.
(by the way, using a 555 to generate 125 kHz to modulate the output of a microcontroller that you're programming yourself: that's redundant, simply use a PWM unit of the microcontroller to do the modulation yourself, that's far easier and removes the 555 completely, thankfully.)
Then: The receiving end needs to deal with strong interferers. Since the interferer's power has an easier time affecting the voltage on the grid when its impedance is high, you get bad noise exactly when you have an easy-to-deal-with impedance, and vice versa. So, your receiver needs extensive filtering, and very likely error correction to go any further.
On top of that, a 125 kHz square wave is a really bad choice for an easy-to-build device to make for a carrier: the fundamental is very much in the region of what a lot of devices, especially switch-mode supplies, cause in interference, and the square wave shape means you waste a lot of energy in harmonics that you won't be able to use for recovery of the signal.
So, go with a sinusoidal carrier(s), do the usual things that communications people do: Don't use OOK! OOK sounds simple to transmit, but its very bad BER performance means your receiver needs to be unnecessarily complicated to achieve the same error rate than a (relatively) still simple transmitter.
You'll find that simple powerline devices tend to use FSK – quite commonly even multi-tone FSK. If I were you, I'd start with that:

Be aware that you're about to break multiple laws if you attach this to an actual installation power grid


You're building an intentional transmitter without a license
You're attaching a communications device that has no type approval to the power grid, causing interference to grid control infrastructure (depending on who operates your grid)
And on top of that, you're handling grid voltage, which is an inherent risk: electrocution and fires can result from improperly designed devices and improper handling, and frankly, you don't seem to have been trained in this!


Bury your 555. It makes everything harder, and we have no need for it
Use your transmitting microcontrollers's PWM unit to generate two different tones that are maybe a factor of 1.2 apart from each other: far enough to be easy to tell apart, and close enough to not be affected too differently by the frequency-selective channel. (the ATMega32 has no sufficient PLLs and clock dividers for a good choice of frequencies. This might mean you want something else.) Also, putting both frequency much closer than an octave means your analog filter to remove the harmonics can keep simple.
It's not untypical that a low-complexity powerline transmitter simply doesn't use the "worst" part of your 100 Hz half-cycles, so clearly, you'll need to have enough buffer for the data to be sent during that period. Which might indicate your ATMega32 is not the right tool for the transmitting side – you need sommething with more RAM. Also, adding checksum or, better, forward-error correction redundancy at the transmitter is practically inevitable in a typical residential or industrial PLC application.
Your transmitter's analog frontend, as said, will have to deal with low impedance (after all, the grid's job is to keep the voltage 50 Hz sinusoidal, no matter the load, so at 50 Hz, the grid impedance is, to a relatively good approximation, 0 Ω; by tendency, the higher the frequency, the higher the impedance, but also the higher the losses). You will need to filter out the harmonics (as mentioned above). No shortcuts there, you'd loose too much power in your frontend, and you'll need to amplify, and impedance-transform for grid impedance. Since you don't want the grid 50 Hz (and the other devices' emissions) to fry your electronics, you'll need to couple in the signal with a high-pass characteristic. So, transformers, Y-capacitors, and quite likely a push-pull power stage design are upon you. As mentioned in the comments, companies who make analog frontend ICs for powerline applications will happily sell you frontend ICs, and you'll see the minimum effort you need to spend on discrete electronics for coupling these to your actual power line is still substantial. Look at the application notes and eval boards for these chips!
Your receiver can, luckily, be rather high-impedance; you just need to track the cyclostationary attenuation your signal sees. Which means your Atmega32 on the receiving end is probably far too weak in terms of computational power: aside from a properly filtering, protecting and coupling frontend, you need an ADC that samples at the desired rate, you need logic to detect a preamble, and something estimate the channel's characteristics based on that. Luckily, for a slow 2-FSK that's easy. For 9600 bd, however, you're already occupying ~10 kHz in bandwidth, so your FSK spacing needs to be > 10 kHz, and that means your symbol decision might need to take into account that both tones get attenuated by different amounts. In essence, you need a (simplistic) equalizer.
In software, after your ADC'ing, you'd filter better, adaptively amplify (multiply) the carrier frequency, make a decision based on the relative strength of your received tones, and then would get your data back out. This is no job for an ancient 8-bit microcontroller as you chose; this calls for something with more than a couple kilobytes of RAM, multiplication instructions that don't take ages, enough DMA engines to support getting data from the ADC while doing calculations… Sounds like a mid- to higher-end microcontroller to me, something like an arm cortex-m based microcontroller. Apply any error correction your transmitter added, undo the packetization, and emit the data.

TLDR
That all goes to say: if you think this was going to be "attaching a 555 to the grid", I'll have to disappoint you. At that level of simplicity, systems do exist, but they are used to reset clocks to 12:00 once a day, or to turn on street lighting – and they have replaced by much more complicated systems, because to achieve that, the transmitters had to put out literal megawatts of power. And they are far from being powerful enough to transmit 9600 bits per second. Sorry.

I did find the TI Application Note Using THVD80x0 Devices to Communicate Over an AC Outlet which can use an OOK carrier frequency of 125KHz with possibly a data rate of up to 12.5 Kbps. Not sure how difficult it is to create a robust type approved powerline communication device.

@ChesterGillon I find the block diagram on Page 3 to be rather illuminating on that. If you are in the business of building your own transceiver, you're not only implementing the THVD80x0's functionality, but also the line driver, protection and High-Voltage (HV) interface – which is exactly the things I talk about in my paragraphs on the transmitter's analog frontend. So, as someone who did his master's thesis on design of PLC systems for 230 V nodes, ahem, it's difficult. Note that in the application note they take one very important shortcut: they add series inductors

… on every power load and every power source. You can't do that in your residential installation. Your dishwasher doesn't have a special 125 kHz-blocking filter, and neither does your connection to the power grid.
